# preloader when add my nested movie clip recieve the following error

Tags: flash, actionscript

ERROR 1046: Type was not found or was not compile-time constant:textline.

i have nested my animation into a movie clip and have tried to use a pre-loader on it

the nested movie clip opening screen as a button on and the second screen as back and forward buttons.

the movie clip works fine no problem until adding it to the pre-loader

the code for the pre-loader is (below) on frame 1 frame 2 to is tells it to stop and also were my nested movie clip is

```
function loadProgress(my_content:ProgressEvent):void
 {

var percent:Number = Math.floor( (my_content.bytesLoaded*100)/my_content.bytesTotal          );
myLoadText.text = percent + "%";
 }
function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
currentFrame + 1;
}
loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);
loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pre-loader and nested movie clip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574267/pre-loader-and-nested-movie-clip)

Answer (score 0):

This post is a duplicate if you can send the file some how or upload it to a server i will fix it, for now delete this question as you have duplicate questions on the same topic