# pre-loader and nested movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm using a simple pre-loader which loads a nested MovieClip. Now I'm trying to use it on another project were the nested is a simple photo gallery were users can click on prev or next slides this works fine until  adding the pre-loader if I just use a nest MovieClip with no user control it works as soon as I add a button to frame 2 it throws this error:

> 1046: Type was not found or was not compile-time constant: Textline.

Trying to get the pre-loader to start and then users click on a button to continue with the program

**Code for pre loader**

```
function loadProgress(my_content:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percent:Number = Math.floor((my_content.bytesLoaded * 100)  /my_content.bytesTotal);
    myLoadText.text = percent + "%";
}

function loadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    currentFrame + 1;
}

loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);
loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
```

**Code for first line in the nested movie clip**

```
start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler1);

stop();

function mouseDownHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first! Do not put actionscript inside of movieClips, because more frequent errors accur, missing properties or assets, duplicate properties referencing issues ect..

I assume your referencing something that does not exist/ if you can post the file i can fix your problem